# Insert CLOB / BLOB values read from a File - maven - mybatis

Tags: maven-plugin, mybatis, database-migration, flyway

this is my problem I have this project that host document templates in database (CLOB) and when a change is made we have to promote to all changes to all environments.

I'm looking for a solution where when a change is done to a template file this gets promoted to all registered databases using mybatis migration tool, flyway or something similar so it can be integrated with a continouos integration tool.

I haven't seen any documentation where something like this is possible neither in mybatis nor flyway (maven plugins)

I'm thinking it is something like this:

```
<<migration.sql file>>

--:content1=file://somelocation/file

insert into clob_table (id, content) values (clob_table_sequense.nextval, :content1)
```

Thanks on advance your comments

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from the **Flyway** perspective, this can be easily achieved using [**Java Migrations**](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/JavaMigration)

Comment: Ok, but how? there is no documentation about this. Can you point me to an example?

Comment: @ChatoCrate In your Java migration class, use the jdbcTemplate parameter to inject your files (using standard Java's InputStreams) into your table.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to code anything, then my whole migration depends on a custom project rather than on a tested solid plugin. I was just wondering if doing this is possible to do inside the .sql migration script, but I think you just gave me the answer. :) thanks guys

Comment: Here is an example how it can be done. You have to write the java-part, but it runs from `db.migration`. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/getstarted/advanced/java